# How to justify this orthogonality?

Tags: vectors

I am trying to justify the orthogonality of two vectors but I am stuck.
First here is the figure :
[image]
I want to justify the orthogonality of vector CQ and vector PR.
We know that :

- ABCD is a square.
- DR = AP
- P is on AB
- R is on AD

Here is a dot product : CQ.(AR-AP) (these are all vectors).
I develop it with : CQ.AR - CQ.AP.
I can say that CQ.AR = DR.AR and that CQ.AP = BP.AP.
It's here that I am stuck, I just don't know at all what to do !
*BTW sorry, I don't know how to create the arrows for the vectors.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the side of the square to be equal $1$, and $|AP|=x$.

Then $P=(x,0), R=(0,1-x), Q=(x,1-x), C=(1,1)$, and the vectors are
$$\overrightarrow{CQ} = (x-1,-x)$$
$$\overrightarrow{PR} = (-x,1-x)$$

Meaning
$$\overrightarrow{CQ} \cdot \overrightarrow{PR} = (-x^2+x)+(-x+x^2) = 0$$

Comment: I think you mean $C=(1,1)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It's very clear now !

Answer (score 2):

Let $i=\overrightarrow{AB}$, $j=\overrightarrow{AD}$. By assumption there is a real number $t\in(0,1)$  such that $\overrightarrow{AP}=ti$ and $\overrightarrow{AR}=(1-t)j$, So 
$\overrightarrow{AQ}=ti+(1-t)j$. Also, $AC=i+j$. Thus
$$
\overrightarrow{PR}=\overrightarrow{AR}-\overrightarrow{AP}=-ti+(1-t)j,\quad
\overrightarrow{CQ}=\overrightarrow{AQ}-\overrightarrow{AC}=(t-1)i-tj
$$
So 
$$\overrightarrow{PR}\cdot\overrightarrow{CQ}=-t(t-1)-t(1-t)=0$$
Which is the desired conclusion.